# Issue downloading Python Panda's module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a programming novice, so apologize in advance if I'm asking a dumb question or perpetrating some site etiquette violation. I have tried very hard to research the answer to my question on an issue that seems to be very common, but none of the proposed solutions have worked, so am looking for some help as I just don't know what to try next.

I'm trying to import Panda from iPython onto Windows 8.   I have version 2.7 of Python and have successfully downloaded  Numpy.  Given the suggestions on this site, I have downloaded all the file that I think Panda is dependent on (pytx, dateutil, setuptools), but it still didn't work:  the error message includes:

```
Import Error Traceback (most recent call)
<ipython-input-2-d6ac987968b6> in <module>()
try
from.import hashtable, tslib, lib
except exception: # pragma: no cover
import datetime

- C: \Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>():

Import Error: No module named six
```

Out of desperation, I also deleted all previous version of pandas and loaded Aneconda, thinking from previous responses that might help capture all required modules including Pandas, but the same error keeps coming up.

Any help would be much appreciated, and don't worry about pointing out the obvious (since it's clearly not obvious to me.)

Comment: Anaconda should have fixed this for you, it's possible that it didn't get registered as the default Python version, or that you need to run IPython from the shortcut in the Anaconda start menu folder. In my experience, Anaconda is the easiest option for getting libraries going on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get modules up and running on Windows is to use Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository. It includes installers for a ton of (mainly scientific-related) modules, including pandas, matplotlib, six, etc. Since many modules included compiled extensions, installing using `pip` doesn't always work if the package maintainer hasn't published a binary for your package of interest. Gohlke's packages include everything already pre-compiled, you just need to choose the version and bit-ness of Python, and download the `.exe` files.